# Is there a better way to return last inserted ID for multi insert?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PHP to add 95 new rows to my MySQL DB and return new row ID. The execution time takes around 24 seconds. If I go past 30 seconds, PHP will stop executing (default time limit 30 seconds).

I need to return the row ID for each row inserted so that I can use it to install associated data.

My current solution is this:

```
  /* snippets from my class objects to illustrate my code */

  // This foreach takes 24 seconds on just 95 rows
  foreach($list as $row) {
    $id = $this->importRows($sid,$table)

    array_push($id_list,$id);
  }

  /* PDO insertion */
  protected function importRows($row) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (name, colour)
            VALUES $row['name'], $row['colour']";

    $result = $this->db->exec($sql);
    return $this->db->lastInsertId();
  }
```

To reduce insettion time, I'm hoping I can insert multiple rows in one query
According to [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/information-functions.html) (scroll down to the red lind and the word IMPORTANT) it says:

> If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement,
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted
>   row only.

The solution they suggest is to create another table and inset the new ID's there, then I can fetch the new id's by a select statement at the end.

Has anyone worked on a similar solution? Any suggestions on how I can make thisa bit more time effective?

Comment: There is an example of using php built in method to get last insert id http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: @Sumair Zafar, That's what `$this->db->lastInsertId()` is using PDO.

Answer (score 3):

this is the trick I used to use in such cases:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO my_table (name, colour) VALUES";
$i = 0;
foreach( $rows as $row ) {
    if( $i ) $query .= ',';
    $query .= " ( $row[ 'name' ],
              IF( @id$i := LAST_INSERT_ID(), $row[ 'colour' ], $row[ 'colour' ] ) )";
    ++$i;
}
$result = $this->db->exec( $query );
```

then have a query like this to fetch the ids:

```
SELECT @id1, @id2, @id3, ...
```

Comment: You can use `@ids:=CONCAT(@ids, ',' ,LAST_INSERT_ID())` for unknown id counts! @Steven

Answer (score 0):

1. lock table
2. add your data using one 'insert'
3. unlock table
4. get last insert id
5. other id's can be computed: `id[n]=last_insert_id+n`, where n is number of your inserted line

Comment: Just a quick note: It seems to be possible that "lastInsertId" returns the id of the first line or the last line that has been inserted. It depends on something in server configuration. I don't know where this can be changed but I had both behaviours. It's fixed on a system base, though, so if you get the first when you try you'll always get the first - not random :)

Comment: -1 this is so error prone. if some `insert` stmt has failed, the numbers will be off. Not to mention concurrent transactions. Not to mention locking a table is never a good idea.

Comment: Shouldn't 3. and 4. be swapped?

Comment: @Adrian, why is it a bad idea to lock the table? is `LAST_INSERT_ID()` on MySql only restricted to the current session? And therefore no point in locking the table?